# A way to get catch double tap in lock screen android?

Tags: android, double-click, lockscreen

Is there a way to catch some thing like double_tap event (with a `BroadcastReceiver` of some kind, anything of similar sort or something else)?

I have a service to show the `View` by adding to
`WindowManager` ( `FLAG = TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR`) .

It displays ok on lockscreen but it seems I can only unlock screen when i delete this view ( may be the higher priority of this view - So i have to remove it and unlock screen normally).

Any way to do this ? many thanks

sorry for my  unclear question. No need DoubleTapToWake, i mean lockscreen , not the "black screen" when device sleep :)

**UPDATE:**

I want to find a way that I can catch a event ( double tab, swipe,..). And the device does not need to Root and use this app normally.

I used `AppTabWidget` but it doesn't seem to be the correct way. I have no idea, and so no code to share....
Example: http://techcrunch.com/2014/07/07/lokloks-new-messaging-app-lets-you-draw-on-your-friends-lock-screen/

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Post your `code` what you have done so far?

Comment: Why do you want to catch a double tap event when the screen is locked? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi suragch. I want to create a app that can help androider can interact with "picture image" in lockscreen.... From 5.0 android remove appwidget to display it self on lock screen,....   So I want to find a new way to do this.... thanks for your question ^.,,.^

Comment: By the "double tap on lock screen" u mean when the phone is locked (by using the power switch) or when you can see the screen with some lock on it ?

Comment: Yes when I can see the screen with some lock on it.

Comment: @kemdo the app you linked as an example is a lockscreen replacement

Answer (score 0):

This will require kernel changes to be supported in all the phones.DoubleTapTo wake kernels are provided by various developers. From application level you cannot do much when screen is locked in android.

Comment: PLease see the app that interact with lockscreen: http://techcrunch.com/2014/07/07/lokloks-new-messaging-app-lets-you-draw-on-your-friends-lock-screen/

Comment: I will not be able to test this app for now. One question: Does this app support DoubleTapToWake in all phones ? Because this is your main question .

Comment: sorry for my  unclear question. No need DoubleTapToWake, i mean lockscreen , not the "black screen" when device sleep :)

Comment: @kemdo the app you linked to replace the lock screen